safari webpush deliver event implementation
I am newbie for safari webpush notification and want to implement deliver event in existing system where we are able to target only safari webpush tokens and end user able to see webpush notifications on their safari browser but delivered event is not being implemented.

I am trying to explain my current implementation using above mentioned diagram where zip file is getting read by perl component and if validation got succeed we got safari notification optin requesting permission and token will get saved in our system after giving permission.I have read couple of links where i come to know we can't track delivered event via JS and it has tobe implemented on server only but i am not sure how i can implement this.
